# Creating a calculate + clear button Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Can anyone explain why the add and clear buttons are not working? Also, could someone provide advice on how I should structure this code to add and clear my label?

Originally my `add` command summed the inputs and created a label but I realized my `clear()` function won't be able to access the local label variable to clear it up.

My next thought was to create a global `label_result` variable and just changing it with the result in my add function and clearing it in my `clear()` function.

However I get an error
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'config' Exception in Tkinter callback`.

```
from tkinter import*

class Window:
    def __init__(self,root,title,geometry):
        self.root=root
        self.root.title(title)
        self.root.geometry(geometry)

    def dynamic_button(self,text,command):
        dynamic_button = Button(self.root,text=text,command=command)
        dynamic_button.grid()

    def label(self,text):
        label1 = Label(self.root,text=text)
        label1.grid()

    def input(self):
        input=Entry(self.root)
        input.grid()
        return input


def add():
    result = int(input1.get()) + int(input2.get())
    result_label.config(text=result)

def clear():
    result_label.config(text="")

root=Tk()
window1 = Window(root,"Practice GUI","550x400")
result_label = window1.label(text="")

input1 = window1.input()
input2 = window1.input()

calculate_button = window1.dynamic_button("Calculate",add)
clear_button = window1.dynamic_button("Clear",clear)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: At least part of the problem is that your `Window.lable()` function doesn't return a value, so assigning its return value to `result_label` gives it a value of `None`. Once I fixed that by added a `return label1` statement at the end, the Clear button worked.

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked! Could you explain a bit on why I require the return label1? I'm trying to understand this a bit better

Comment: All functions return some kind of value, usually via a `return` statement somewhere inside of them. However if the function ends without encountering (and/or executing) such a statement, Python implicitly does a `return None`.

Comment: Appreciate the response, makes sense. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It will probably be easier if you structured your code like this.

```
from tkinter import *

class Window:
    def __init__(self,root,title,geometry):
        self.root=root
        self.root.title(title)
        self.root.geometry(geometry)

        #input 1
        self.input_1 = Entry(self.root)
        self.input_1.pack()

        #input 2
        self.input_2 = Entry(self.root)
        self.input_2.pack()

        #add button
        self.add_Btn = Button(self.root, text="Calculate", command=self.add)
        self.add_Btn.pack()

        #clear button
        self.clear_Btn = Button(self.root, text="Clear", command=self.clear)
        self.clear_Btn.pack()

        #result label
        self.label = Label(self.root)
        self.label.pack()

    def add(self):
        try:
            total = int(self.input_1.get())+int(self.input_2.get())
            self.label["text"] = f"Sum is {total}."
        except ValueError:
            pass

    def clear(self):
        self.input_1.delete(0, 'end')
        self.input_2.delete(0, 'end')
        self.label["text"] = ""

root=Tk()
window1 = Window(root,"Practice GUI","550x400")

root.mainloop()
```